# How to know if there is any similar elements in two set

Tags: python

this is my code can any one pinpoint where i was mistaken ?
I am new to the coding so i expect help from the community

```
first_set  = (1,2,3,4)
second_set = (2,7,5,4)
m = len(first_set)
n = len(second_set)
a = 0 
b = 0
for a in range(m):
for b in range(n):

while first_set[a]==second_set[b]:
 print (first_set[a])
This prints 2 in whole screen :(
```

Comment: `while first_set[a]==second_set[b]:` You never change `a` or `b` inside the `while` loop so it loops infinitely when they are equal.

Comment: You are using tuples not sets in your example, and the indentation is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection) to get the common elements of two sets.

```py
a = set([1,2,3])
b = set([4,5,3])

print(a.intersection(b))  # {3}
print(a & b)  # shorthand version of the above
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any indentation so the first_set[a] and second_set[b] its stuck on the first element. Try replacing while with if or make a new line where you make second_set and first_set move to next element

// this would be the corect form

```
first_set  = (1,2,3,4)
second_set = (2,7,5,4)
m = len(first_set)
n = len(second_set)
a = 0 
b = 0
for a in range(m):
    for b in range(n):
        if first_set[a]==second_set[b]:
            print (first_set[a])

It's all about the tabs ;c
```

Comment: How do I get good with the indentation ?
also thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.  First, you can use curly braces to define sets:

```
first_set = {1, 2, 3, 4}
second_set = {2, 7, 5, 4}
```

Now, you don't need len() or range() or index variables to loop over sets:

```
for a in first_set:
    for b in second_set:
        #do something
```

Next, the while loop is getting stuck as soon as you find two elements that are the same, this should be an if block instead:

```
for a in first_set:
    for b in second_set:
        if a == b:
            print(a)
```

And lastly, as others have pointed out, this is a simple set intersection and python has built-in support for it.